# How does http-authentication for TinyMCE has to look like?

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, tinymce

My problem is, that I don't know how to secure TinyMCE.
A .htaccess with

```
deny from all
```

doesn't work, because Tiny's javascripts needs to be accessible from the client.

What do I have to write into the .htaccess in order to both protect TinymCE and keep it working?

Thank you!

Comment: TinyMCE by itself isn't a security risk. It's the PHP file that it submits to. That file should be able to authenticate the user and secure itself against malicious input. Unless you know the IP address of whomever is using that form, you don't want to use a .htaccess to secure it.

Comment: ok, thank you! You mean the php-file that contents the submit-form?

Comment: Yes, wherever you submit the form that you use TinyMCE on. TinyMCE is only loaded up in the browser and doesn't do anything on the server by itself, so you don't need to secure it.

Comment: But I have read (don't know where), that I should avoid, that TinyMCE-files should be accessed directly from the client, because it can be used to upload files from outside (without logging in)?

Comment: Not unless your PHP script is set up to accept file uploads.

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: Did you write any code to accept file uploads? If not, then you're fine.